# Need help converting If/then to CASE in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I'm having some trouble grasping the use of CASE statements (used to using If/Then). I would like to convert this to CASE format:

```
If DATEPART(Month,Datetime) = 04
       Then UPDATE DB1
       SET column1 = (SELECT Value FROM DB2)
```

So if the month of the current datetime matches 4 (April), then update column1 of DB1 with the values in the Value column of DB2. How would this look using CASE?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*. It computes a *value*.

Answer (score 2):

I am unclear what `case` has to do with this.  The `case` statement would normally be used in a `select` to execute conditional statements.  Your `update` seems more like:

```
update db1
    set column1 = db2.value
    from db1 join
         db2
         on db1.foo = db2.bar
    where DATEPART(Month, db1.Datetime) = 4;
```

But it is a bit hard to divine from your question what you are really trying to do.

EDIT:  (in response to comment)

For todays date, the `where` clause should be:

```
where datepart(month, getdate()) = 4
```

Instead of the `where`, you can use `if (datepart(month, getdate()) = 4) . . .`.

The `join` (or subquery) is needed because the question refers to two tables.

Comment: +1 : Although `DATEPART(Month, db1.Datetime);` seems to be missing `= 4`, and I *think* the OP wants to test *today's date* rather than the dates in a table.

Comment: ^^^ You are correct. I only want the update function to execute IF the current month (of today's date) is april. Does the above code still apply? Also what is the "on db1.foo = db2.bar" for?

Comment: What is the "on db1.foo = db2.bar" referring to? I'm not sure how to relate that to my table.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF ((SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, GetDate())) = 04)
  UPDATE
    db1
  SET
    column1 = db2.value
  FROM
    db2
  WHERE
    db1.key = db2.key
```

The `DATEPART()` is embedded in a `SELECT` which is itself enclosed in `()`.

The `WHERE` clause is needed to specify which rows in db2 are used to update which rows in db1.

In T-SQL there is no `THEN`.  See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) for details.

Comment: The columns in both tables are the same size (5 rows) and I want to move all rows. What would the where clause look like for that?

Comment: I removed the where statement completely but it only copies the first value from db2 into all the rows of db1.

Comment: @user3532047 - What is *functionally* happening is that ***all*** 5 rows from `db2` are being copied into each row in db1, 5 rows written in to row 1, the same 5 rows written again in to row 2, etc, etc.  Each of the 5 writing over the previous and so you only see the last value written.  What you ***need*** is a `id` column in each table that allows you to state `WHERE db1.id = db2.id`.  Do your tables have a column (or columns) that allow you to uniquely identify the rows?  It's just like a `JOIN`; you need something to tell the RDBMS that `this row from db2 lines up with that row from db1`.

Comment: I don't have an ID column. I'm not sure I can since these tables get truncated completely every time the query is ran.

Comment: @user3532047 - Then how do you determine which row to put each value in to?  There must be some kind of logic such that if you drew db1 and db2 on paper, you could draw 5 arrows, one from each value in db2, each pointing to a different row in db1 saying `this goes to here`?

Comment: It's strictly top to bottom. As in if rows were numbered 1-5 from top to bottom, 1-5 from db2 go into 1-5 of db1.

Comment: @user3532047 - There is no such thing in an RDBMS.  There is no guaranteed order to a set of data, *you* need to create it using `ORDER BY` on some identifying column(s).  Another way of saying that is that there is no concept of row (element) 1 in a table; it's an unordered set, not an array.  Until you create your own sortable fields.  Which means that, unfortunately, you're going to need to create and populate the fields you need to enable a 1:1 join.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is equal CASE statement for your query.

Check CASE express in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

> Evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.

Your query is a conditional UPDATE operation which doesn't return anything. Could you clarify your intention here?

Comment: See the first answer. That code works for me, just need to know how to specify to copy ALL rows.

Comment: I understand that works. However, if statement doesn't execute UPDATE when condition is false. For the first answer, it scan all table entire even you just want a simple date check. It's huge performance difference. I'm not sure if SQL Server is smart enough to omit UPDATE when WHERE clause is false.  To copy all rows, you need to specify the relationship between DB1 and DB2. That's where foo and bar come from.

Comment: I'm not sure how to specify that relationship....I tried putting in the column names again instead of foo and bar but it didn't copy anything.